# No main mainfest attribute in jar file

Tags: java, jar, attributes, program-entry-point

Hi I have downloaded one browser mob jar file which I have to load for my test cases
I run this by following command:

```
java -jar browsermob-rest-2.1.0-beta-2-sources.jar
```

But here it gives me an error like:

> no main manifest attribute, in browsermob-rest-2.1.0-beta-2-sources.jar

So what do I have to do to resolve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "which I have to load for my test cases"? Where do you need this jar?

Comment: First, if you want to run it somehow you have to build it (for instance with maven) or to use jar with class-files like from here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.lightbody.bmp/browsermob-rest/2.1.0-beta-2 . But there is no main class either. Have a look at this for details: https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy/